# Efficiency of query using NOT IN()?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a query that runs on my server:

```
DELETE FROM pairing WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT f.id FROM info f)
```

It takes two different tables, `pairing` and `info` and says to `DELETE` all entries from `pairing` whenever the `id` of that pairing is not in `info`.

I've run into an issue on the server where this is beginning to take too long to execute, and I believe it has to do with the efficiency (or lack of constraints in the `SELECT` statement).

However, I took a look at the MySQL `slow_log` and the number of compared entries is actually  **LOWER**  than it should be. From my understanding, this should be O(mn) time where m is the number of entries in `pairing` and n is the number of entries in `info`. The number of entries in `pairing` is 26,868 and in `info` is 34,976.

This should add up to 939,735,168 comparisons. But the `slow_log` is saying there are only 543,916,401: almost half the amount.

I was wondering if someone could please explain to me how the efficiency of this specific query works. I realize the fact that it's performing quicker than I think it should is a blessing in this case, but I still need to understand where the optimization comes from so that I can further improve upon it.

Comment: You can use also EXPLAIN (or EXPLAIN PLAN if you use Oracle) to see exactly what is being done by database server

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how exactly I would use that keyword?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Mysql :
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM pairing WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT f.id FROM info f)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used the slow query log much (at all) but isn't it possible that the difference can just be chalked up to simple... can't think of the word. Basically, *939,735,168* is the theoretical worst case scenario where the query literally checks every single row except the one it needs to first. Realistically, with a roughly even distribution (and no use of indexing), a check of row in `pairing` will on average compare to half the rows in `info`.

It looks like your real world performance is only 15% off (worse) than what would be expected from the "average comparisons".

*Edit: Actually, "worse than expected" should be expected when you have rows in `pairing` that are not in `info`, as they will skew the number of comparisons.*

---

...which is still not great. If you have id indexed in both tables, something like this should work a lot faster.

```
DELETE pairing 
FROM pairing LEFT JOIN info ON pairing.id = info.id 
WHERE info.id IS NULL
;
```

This should take advantage of an index on `id` to make the comparisons needed something like O(NlogM).

Comment: How does the `WHERE info.id IS NULL` help? I'm only looking for when an entry is not in the entire table. That's saying look for `info.id` that is NULL

Comment: WHERE happens logically after JOIN, so left join "results" of `pairing`s without `info` records will have info.id IS NULL.

Comment: When I tried this query on the server, it deleted everything from the `pairing` table, not just entries that didn't exist in `info`. Luckily I had a backup to restore all the data.

Comment: Is the join condition appropriate? I had my doubts about it, but don't know the specifics of your schema so just went with what was in your query.

Comment: It should be, but for some reason the query went haywire. Would possibly 'ORDER BY' help in the original query when in the select statement? I feel if both tables were sorted by id that may help efficiency

Comment: I don't think an ORDER BY would help; it wouldn't add/imply temporary indexes that could help. I am thinking you should add the CREATE statements for the two tables, and maybe a little sample data, to your question (up top).

Comment: `IS NULL` is needed for `LEFT JOIN` so that it acts like `NOT IN`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is unlikely to help -- without it, the Optimizer can do what if wants, and that will probably be best.